# Find the image of the annulus $1\leq |z|\leq e$ under the principal value of the logarithm.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

I am asked to find the image of the annulus $1\leq |z| \leq e$ under the principal value of the logarithm and I am having a hard time understanding exactly what this question is asking.

I know that the principal value of some $a^b$ is defined by $a^b:=exp(bLog(a))$ and I know that the principal logarithm is defined by $Log(z):=ln|z|+iArg(z)$.

I think my goal is to create a function of $z$ with these definitions but I don't understand how I should do this- whether I need to somehow combine these definitions or if I am just to use one of them? Specifically, is the principal value of the logarithm the same as the principal logarithm, in that I can simply use the function $f(z)=ln|z|+iArg(z)$ to determine the image of the annulus?

Comment: Let $w=\log(z)=\ln|z|+iArg(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use $f(z)=\ln|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)$

You have from the question $1\leq |z| \leq e$ so $0 \leq \ln(|z|) \leq 1$

Since you are taking the principal value, you have $-\pi \lt \operatorname{Arg}(z)  \leq \pi$

So the image of the annulus under $\operatorname{Log} z$ is the rectangle on the Argand diagram with real part in $[0,1]$ and imaginary part in $(-\pi,\pi]$